# Highlight selected category/sub category when selected (Woocomerce category widget )

Tags: css, widget, styles, categories

I am trying to style the woocomerce widget, where the selected category or subcategory gets highlighted (together with the count link) upon selection (active/current).

I tried a lot, but there is a trick there that I am not able to figure.

This is the page: https://allb.cloudaccess.host/right-sidebar/

Answer (score 1):

When you inspect the categories with the developer tool of your browser you can see that the active category gets the class `current-cat` added to the div.

Now you can style it with:

```
.current-cat{
      //Styles for the div here
      a{
          //Styles for the link here
      }
}
```